# How to use suspend modifier in Room Dao after kotlin upgrade to 1.6.0?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dao

Upgrading kotlin to 1.6.0 causes Room Dao suspend modifier to break build project with error: "Not sure how to handle query method's return type........".

Are there(here) any solutions other than a workaround for running Dao functions withContext(Disapatchers.IO) in repository?

Comment: For my insert & delete functions i just removed the `suspend` keyword. For my Querys i used a return type of `Flow<MyQueryResult>`. However, this just removing the suspend feels like cheating :(

Comment: Yes. I've removed it too. I could not find right way. What was changed. How to deal with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue yesterday with the upgrade of Kotlin 1.6.0.

My working project started to fail, same error messages.

After searching in some other forums someone mentioned to change roomVersion to "**2.4.0-beta02**". And.. surprisingly it worked! At least it compiled without any more issues.

Try it , hopefully it will work for you too.

Mine is defined in a variable:

def  roomVersion = "2.4.0-beta02"

So the rest of the dependencies for Room should take advantage of this change.

Comment: Never considered using beta libraries. It's time to do it.

Comment: Neither do I . But, for some reason Room 2.3.0 is breaking with Kotlin 1.6. I expect Room 2.4.0 to be available soon.

Comment: Never mind it's now stable, I 've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

The new Kotlin compiler (aka `1.6.+`) needs room version `2.4.0` at least to support the language. So Upgrade your room dependency to `2.4.0`.

And since you are using the version of room you also have to target Android `API 31`.

[Room 2.4.0 changes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_240_2)

Comment: But why do we have to go through breaking changes like this every time the language is updated? That's the reason why you cannot accept any AS update with confidence. Always a risk of breaking something that  was working fine before.

Comment: Agree, we are always afraid of upgrading, we want to spend time developing, not how to overcome those breaking changes!